# Attempting to copy a .zip file over SMB results in "Invalid argument"

Tags: macos, vpn, smb

I am on OS X Yosemite. I have connected to my work via VPN. I have mounted a share on the VPN over SMB. I can see the `.zip` file that I want (I just created it) but I cannot copy it:

```
Rammy:Main phrogz$ pwd
/Volumes/public/foo/bar/Main

Rammy:Main phrogz$ ll *.zip
-rwx------  1 phrogz  staff    76M Nov 22 21:47 Lux.zip*

Rammy:Main phrogz$ cp Lux.zip ~/Documents/Work
cp: Lux.zip: Invalid argument
```

I can copy some other files from the same directory without issue, but others give me the same problem. I can rename the file from the command line without issue.

Is this an SMB issue? A problem with the file size? A problem with Yosemite?

How can I get this (and other) files copied? I kinda need them.

---

<sub>In case it's relevant, the file was created with 7-zip, and the VPN software is Cisco AnyConnect.</sub>

Comment: Have you tried `cp /Volumes/public/foo/bar/Main/Lux.zip ~/Documents/Work` ?